# Questions regarding simulating Central Limit Theorem from Book Data Science from Scratch

Tags: python, matplotlib, probability, data-science

I was reading the book Data Science From scratch by Joel Grus. My question is specifically concerning Chapter 6, where the author was using binomial random variable to simulate the theorem.

The result would be a chart with the probability distribution of the binomial trials and an approximation plot using normal distribution. The two plots should be very similar to each other. The book shows a chart like this:
[Author's Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlQ1Q.png)

The codes he provided are:

```
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

def bernoulli_trial(p):
    return 1 if random.random() < p else 0

def binomial(n, p):
    return sum(bernoulli_trial(p) for _ in range(n))

def make_hist(p, n, num_points):
    data = [binomial(n, p) for _ in range(num_points)]
    histogram = Counter(data)
    plt.bar([x-0.4 for x in histogram.keys()],
       [v / num_points for v in histogram.values()],
       0.8,
       color='0.75')

    mu = p * n
    sigma = math.sqrt(n * p * (1-p))

    # use a line chart to show the normal approximation
    xs = range(min(data), max(data) + 1)
    ys = [normal_cdf(i+0.5, mu, sigma) - normal_cdf(i-0.5, mu, sigma) for i in xs]
    plt.plot(xs, ys)
    plt.title('Binomial Distribution vs. Normal Approximation')
    plt.show()

make_hist(0.75, 100, 10000)
```

My question is, in this line:
    [normal_cdf(i+0.5, mu, sigma) - normal_cdf(i-0.5, mu, sigma) for i in xs]
why did the author use +0.5 and -0.5? Is there a specific reason for that?

Not sure if anyone has encountered this question. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: normal_cdf as defined in the book is over a vector `x/10.0` in `range(-50,50)`. Right?

Comment: Yes exactly. The function is: def normal_cdf(x, mu=0, sigma=1): return (1+math.erf((x-mu)/math.sqrt(2)/sigma))/2. The x axis is: xs = [x/10.0 for x in range(-50, 50)]. Why divide by 10?

Comment: I guess it is just to shrink the chart to be between -5 to 5 along the x axis?

Comment: Scaling it looks like

Comment: Whenever I hit things in someone's code I don't quite follow, I try changing it to see what happens. Change the values from 0.5 to 1, or something crazy like 1000, just to see. Then you can probably work out why the author chose what he (in this case) did. Kind of like working out extra credit problems in old textbooks. Plus, feels good to learn it yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `xs` variable you have a list of X coordinates with step 1, e.g. [5,6,7,8,9,10]. In `ys` variable you need to get corresponding Y coordinates and `normal_cdf(i+0.5, mu, sigma) - normal_cdf(i-0.5, mu, sigma)` in your code is an integral from i-0.5 to i+0.5, i.e. with the width of (i+0.5) - (i-0.5) = 1, the same step.

More understandable code would look like this:

```
step = 1.0
xs = range(min(data), max(data) + 1, step)
ys = [normal_cdf(i + step / 2, mu, sigma) - normal_cdf(i - step / 2, mu, sigma) for i in xs]
```

Comment: I see! So the range(min(data), max(data) + 1) in the example actually implies that the step is 1.